# Create a 2-D Array From a Group of 1-D Arrays of Different Lengths in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 1-D arrays that I have combined into a single 1-D array and would like to combine them into a 2-D array with 3 columns consisting of the two arrays and the newly created combined array. Ultimately, the objective is to plot all three 1-D arrays on a single chart using Plotly. The values are datetime but I will use integers here for the sake of simplicity.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,4,5,7,9])
b = np.array([2,4,6,8])
c = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
# The created array should be 9 rows and 3 columns that looks like:
abc = np.array([1,0,1],[0,2,2],[3,0,3],[4,4,4],[5,0,5],[0,6,6],[7,0,7],[0,8,8],[9,0,9])
```

Essentially, array abc is the c column repeated 3 times with zeros where there are missing values for a or b. I would prefer to do this in Numpy but am open to alternatives as well. In addition, the zeros don't have to be present and can be substituted with NaN, Null, etc. The questions I've reviewed seem to suggest that there is no way to combine arrays of different lengths but I'm certain there must be a way of combining the arrays by extending the shorter ones using indexing. I'm just having trouble getting from here to there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Pure numpy approach:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,3,4,5,7,9])
b = np.array([2,4,6,8])
c = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
abc = np.zeros((10, 3)) 

# change to a loop, if you like
abc[a, 0] = a 
abc[b, 1] = b 
abc[c, 2] = c 

print(abc[1:])
```

prints:

```
[[1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 2. 2.]
 [3. 0. 3.]
 [4. 4. 4.]
 [5. 0. 5.]
 [0. 6. 6.]
 [7. 0. 7.]
 [0. 8. 8.]
 [9. 0. 9.]]
```

Comment: Very clever. I'm going to try this tomorrow and if it works out I'll credit you with the answer. Regardless of the outcome however, I like the outside-the-box thinking.

Comment: Cool, waiting for your verdict ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach does not appear to work with datetime. Python complains: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices` when I try the `abc[a,0]` with datetime values.

Comment: I admit not seeing that you need datetime, I just solved the example. It is true, the solution will not work for datetime, obvoiusly, you can't index `abc` with a date.
What you could do, is just use my solution and later substitute 1, 2, 3,... for dates you actually need.